# UITableView select added/edited row after reload (with sections)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, sections

Heyhey - new day new fun XD

EDIT: Solution see end of text!

I have following issue:
I have a UITableView which gets its data from CoreData. The TableView is divided in section, using the first letter of the name.
If you click on a cell, u can edit the content of that CoreData-Object on the right side of the screen. If you click the ok button, the new content is saved and the TableView reloads to show the changes. No Problem till now... but:
After editing (or adding) i want the TableView (after its reload) to select the just edited (or added) TableCell.

How can i determin the indexPath and section for edited cell (its possible that its in a new section due changing the name). Any ideas?

EDIT: Ok, i think i can determin the new position in the controller function of (NSFetchedResultsController) - i only have the find the right place;

SOLUTION:
I got it. In the didChangeObject controller (NSFetchedResultsController) i can retrieve the new indexPath which i save in a variable and set the selected row after the reload of the tableView to this new indexPath!

Comment: Post your answer as an answer - it's fine to answer your own question. You might even get some upvotes out of it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I got it. In the didChangeObject controller (NSFetchedResultsController) i can retrieve the new indexPath which i save in a variable and set the selected row after the reload of the tableView to this new indexPath!